# Can't get addClass working on an Img

Tags: jquery, css, image, addclass

I'm working on this form, and instead of boring radio buttons I'm using images that people can click on, and then with jQuery I add the `.prop("checked", true)` to the co-responding radio input.

However, what I thought should have been super simple has been getting the best of me. I'm trying to add the class of "checked" to the image that gets clicked, so that it will corespond with the CSS rule I have that will change the img current opacity from .3 to 1, to let people know it's been "checked". Sounds simple, but for some reason I seem to be missing something.

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xum3sqp/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="r-form">
<div class="thumbs">
<lable name="thumbs">Would you recommend this host?</lable>
<input type="radio" id="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="yes">
<img class="thumb_r" src="/imgs/thumbs-up-green.png">
<input type="radio" id="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="no">
<img class="thumb_r" src="/imgs/thumbs-down-red.png">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.r-form .thumbs {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 95%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5% 0px 0%;
}

.r-form .thumbs lable {
    display: block;
}

.r-form .thumbs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.r-form .thumbs img {

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    opacity: .3;
    margin: 10px 5%;

}

.r-form .thumbs img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.r-form .thumbs img.checked {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var $thumb = $(".thumbs").children("img");

 $thumb.click(function(){

        $(this).siblings("img").removeClass(".checked");
        $(this).addClass(".checked");
        $(this).prev("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
        alert($("this").is(".checked"));

    });

 });
```

**--Note--**

This is only a portion of my code, I have not included the `<form></form>`, but it is in my original. I'm only concerned with the img and getting the button checked.

Comment: You will want to use some template web images so we can see what's happening, you never explained the exact problem in your question.

Comment: I know this is not really an answer to your question, but why use javascript at all for that? Check this out: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers everyone!

However,this problem has been solved. Unfortunately the individual who gave me the answer deleted his answer before I could thank him (for some reason his answer was voted down?) The issue was I was trying to `addClass(".checked")` when what I should have been doing is `addClass("checked")`, **WITHOUT** the period.

I was working in another area of the form, and for some reason, the jQuery would not cooperate with classes (adding or removing) without using the period. Perhaps there's something there I'm not understanding, but it works now.

Thanks again for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is child and not sibling of element with class `.thumbs`. I fix some of the errors in html, like duplicate id, wrong attribute on label. Also jquery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) accepts a string as parameter and no css class selector:

```js
var $thumb = $(".thumbs img");
$thumb.click(function() {
  //remove checked class from other images
  $thumb.removeClass("checked");
  //add checked class to click image
  $(this).addClass("checked");
  $(this).children("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```css
.r-form .thumbs {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 5% 0px 0%;
}
.r-form .thumbs label {
  display: block;
}
.r-form .thumbs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.r-form .thumbs img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: .3;
  margin: 10px 5%;
}
.r-form .thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.r-form .thumbs img.checked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-form">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <label>Would you recommend this host?</label>
    <input type="radio" class="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="yes" />
    <img class="thumb_r" alt="thumb" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100" />
    <input type="radio" class="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="no" />
    <img class="thumb_r"  alt="thumb" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you also have a typo in the HTML ("lable" should be "label"), the label does not need a name but should have a for="" point to the id of the input element you are referring to to ensure that the label is associated with that element.

```
<lable name="thumbs">Would you recommend this host?</lable>
```

should be

```
 <label for="thumbs">Would you recommend this host?</label>
```

Comment: no worries -  have another look at my post - i just amended it to give a better structure to the label and i just noticed a "lable" in the css as well - best to do a global change of all "lable"s to "label"

Comment: I went back to update my code, and after doing a `find` on "Lable", apparently I'd done them all like that. Because I'm special apparently. So an EXTRA thank you for pointing that out =)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a bit, remove the "." at the add/removeClass function and removed the quotes at the "this" on the alert.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   var $thumb = $(".thumbs").children("img");

   $thumb.click(function() {

     $(this).siblings("img").removeClass("checked");
     $(this).addClass("checked");
     $(this).prev("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
     alert($(this).is(".checked"));

   });

 });
```

```css
.r-form .thumbs {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 5% 0px 0%;
}

.r-form .thumbs lable {
  display: block;
}

.r-form .thumbs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.r-form .thumbs img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: .3;
  margin: 10px 5%;
}

.r-form .thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.r-form .thumbs img.checked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-form">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <lable name="thumbs">Would you recommend this host?</lable>
    <input type="radio" id="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="yes">
    <img class="thumb_r" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-q-c-100-100-5.jpg">
    <input type="radio" id="thumbs" name="thumbs" value="no">
    <img class="thumb_r" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-q-c-100-100-3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```